# NPM does not install anything : it hangs

Tags: node.js, npm

Whenever I want to install a module with NPM, it hangs at that stage:

```
npm install express
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/express
```

And that's it. It has that behavior for anything I input instead of *express*. I installed **nodejs** and **nvm** that way (Ubuntu 13.10):

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

I tried looking on the Internet and GitHub and I found a closed issue about npm hanging forever when trying to install a module.. but it was a really old issue. Before I ask the developers, am I missing something obvious ?

I tried compiling both nodejs and npm but the result was the same.

EDIT: `npm install express -verbose` -> http://pastebin.com/tGY3V6Ly
Error:

```
npm info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=140072708810560:error:140770FC:SSL   routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:766:
```

Comment: I think you are talking about NPM. NVM is something else, so don't confuse the two.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

NPM has been having server issues of late. Try running the command with `-verbose` to check and see what is going on, and be patient.

Comment: @Videl when was the last time you tried doing the npm install command? I think npmjs is finally up.

Comment: When I searched, I used the right name **npm** so what I said in the question still holds true. I did not find the answer on the internet.

Comment: Right now, I just did it. I updated my question with the output of the command with -verbose. @Munim

Comment: I also experienced some downtime issues this morning

Comment: @Videl Just saw the pastebin. Nothing looks wrong, except its stuck at fetching the package file from npmjs.org. Can you access `https://registry.npmjs.org/express` directly from your browser?

Comment: Yes I can. I tried copying the content on my local apache2 and redirecting registry.npmjs.org there but.. did not work.

Comment: @Videl if you can access that URL in your browser *without any SSL warnings* or any any issue, then there is no reason why npm install shouldn't work. Just give it some time, it is a bit of a download.

Comment: When I said it hangs, it was to mean forever actually :-/. I installed it on another computer (Windows) and it worked.

Comment: Hm, I left the verbose option and left it for some time, here is the ouput: npm info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=140072708810560:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:766:

Comment: And resolved! I used -> https://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues/2472 (since your the only one that helped me, I put your answer as helping. Maybe you could edit your answer to tell people to turn verbose, be patient, etc ? :p)

Comment: Just FYI: what was happening was that npm does a LOT OF STUFF.  Which I didn't know before.  But -verbose lets me see ALL THE STUFF.  I'm in a bit of shock because, really it's a LOT.  Thank you for showing me down the rabbit hole.

Comment: So as said before, just turn -verbose on and be patient. It takes some time but it eventually completes successfully.

Comment: It's better to check this page https://status.npmjs.org/ before start changing configurations.

Answer (score 9):

It is likely of proxy problem. I didn't set proxy but somewhow this worked for me

```
npm config delete proxy
npm config delete https-proxy
npm set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
```

Comment: This finally worked and I tried literally everything else.

Comment: This fixed it for me too

Answer (score 7):

I had this issue on a BeagleBone Black (low power ARM device) and running npm cache clean seemed to get things moving again.

Answer (score 3):

Try without `https`:

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

Comment: This is not secure and should not be used. https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/ssl/why-is-http-not-secure/

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and I solved by disabling all my firewalls

Comment: For someone reasonable they would disable, install and enable.

Answer (score 2):

After an hour of struggling, I cleaned `.npm` and `node_modesl/.staging` directories, and problem just gone! 
(replace the paths with your own)

`yes|rm /root/.npm/* -R`
`yes|rm /path/to/node_modules/.staging/* -R`
`npm install`

Answer (score 2):

For me, this is what worked:

```
npm cache clean
```

And then I reloaded the terminal window and ran `npm install` again.

Answer (score 1):

I opened console with admin privileges and the ran `npm install` on windows. My problem was fixed with this

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and the problem was in proxy: previously I set up `HTTP_PROXY` environment variable and after removing it `npm install` completed without any error.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem inside a Windows git bash terminal - reinstalling the latest version of git bash fixed it

Answer (score 0):

I was using an older version of node. I used a newer version
Type in Terminal:

```
nvm use stable
```

and then

```
npm i
```

and all worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just found out that the "Killer network suite" was why this wasn't working.
I don't know why but it was throttling connection to the server.

Answer (score 0):

I know its been a while and stuff. But nothing helped, i searched for hours now. My fix was installing Chocolatey, uninstall nodejs and reinstall it with chocolatey. I also installed an older version, for me choco install nodejs --version 15.0.1 worked. Dont know if it either works with a newer version.